# static width at col-xl-* (Bootstrap 4)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-system

How can I forbid at col-xl-* that it stops growing for bigger monitors?
When I view it on my laptop (1280 width) and on the desktop (1920), both applys to col-xl but it's either too big on the desktop or too small on the laptop.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center login-div ">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-5 col-xl-3 col-10 rounded-10 mask"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wrap it in a [`.container`](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) element. By the way, a Bootstrap `.col-*` should always be inside of a `.row` which in turn should always be inside a `.container` or `.container-fluid`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and define a `max-width`, probably for Bootstrap's xl [breakpoint](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options):

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /* xl */

  .your-class {
    background: yellow;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="your-class">Hello</div>
```

Using the above code, elements with class `.your-class` will have a maximum width of 200px if the viewport width is at least 1200px.